# codeigniter is not working in nginx server

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

Codeigniter is not working in nginx server.

It is working fine on other servers, but not working on nginx machine. 
**It is only running index(main route) pg, not running inner pages. Showing the error object not found.**

For example:
http://example.com/CI/   (it is running)
http://example.com/CI/index.php/test  (It is not running. 404 error)

How can I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your nginx server block configuration?

Comment: Sorry. I am not. I am not an authorized person to do that.

Comment: I guess the problem is probably there. Check this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Comment: as @namelivia states, the issue is very likely in your nginx configuration. While CI works perfectly on nginx, the initial setup is a little bit more hands-on than the regular setup with Apache. It's super hard to help you pinpoint the issue if we cannot see the relevant parts of your Nginx.conf and sites-available files though